# Swap ETH to DAI using ISwapRouter from Uniswap

Tags: solidity, remix, hardhat

I am trying to get started with Uniswap V3. As an example, I took the most basic use case: Given X amount of ETH do a swap to DAI. Unfortunately, I am not being able to make it work.

There is already a very similar [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92164/swaping-eth-to-dai-on-uniswap) (with no answer) but slightly different as the code doesn't look like mine.

I am using Hardhat to fork the main-net and then I connect Remix to `localhost:8545`

```bash
npx hardhat node --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{MY_API_KEY}
```

Hardhat config down below:

```json
solidity: {
  compilers: [
    {
      version: "0.8.7",
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 1000,
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can notice (full contract at the very bottom), the contract offers 3 payable functions:

```solidity
function convertExactEthToDai() external payable;
function convertEthToExactDai(uint256 daiAmount) external payable;
function getEstimatedETHforDAI(uint daiAmount) external payable returns (uint256);
```

All of them fail, even getEstimatedETHforDAI, which is fairly simple and readonly (almost). There is no given reason, so I am blind. When I execute the function from Remix, I just get a generic error `"Returned error: Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string"`.
When I look at hardhat console, I see this error:

```bash
eth_sendTransaction
  Contract call:       <UnrecognizedContract>
  Transaction:         0xe17fd5a07ca4a0d5a0f91525a77d21152c41f4dc2a9e59feaac4fec7452ba3a1
  From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  To:                  0xc351628eb244ec633d5f21fbd6621e1a683b1181
  Value:               0 ETH
  Gas used:            52351 of 3000000
  Block #13238807:     0x7471674d8b76462230d687644e20970137640a7b2fe005c264a04c2af35d4985

  Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0xb27308f9f90d607463bb33ea1bebb41c27ce5ab6)
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0xc351628eb244ec633d5f21fbd6621e1a683b1181)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
      at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (D:\Repositories\TheRock\facutherock.blockchain.gettingstarted\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:1582:23)
      at HardhatNode.mineBlock (D:\Repositories\TheRock\facutherock.blockchain.gettingstarted\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:435:16)
      at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (D:\Repositories\TheRock\facutherock.blockchain.gettingstarted\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:1494:18)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider._sendWithLogging (D:\Repositories\TheRock\facutherock.blockchain.gettingstarted\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:129:22)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (D:\Repositories\TheRock\facutherock.blockchain.gettingstarted\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:106:18)
```

Looks like the contract is invalid, however I can in EtherScan the [Quoter](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb27308f9f90d607463bb33ea1bebb41c27ce5ab6) and the [Router](https://etherscan.io/address/0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564)

> Any idea? I really appreciate it.

### Here is the full contract

```solidity
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENCED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
pragma abicoder v2;

import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/IQuoter.sol";

interface IUniswapRouter is ISwapRouter {
    function refundETH() external payable;
}

contract Uniswap3 {
  IUniswapRouter public constant uniswapRouter = IUniswapRouter(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
  IQuoter public constant quoter = IQuoter(0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6);
  address private constant DAI = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;
  address private constant WETH9 = 0xd0A1E359811322d97991E03f863a0C30C2cF029C;

  function convertExactEthToDai() external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "Must pass non 0 ETH amount");

    uint256 deadline = block.timestamp + 15;
    address tokenIn = WETH9;
    address tokenOut = DAI;
    uint24 fee = 3000;
    address recipient = msg.sender;
    uint256 amountIn = msg.value;
    uint256 amountOutMinimum = 1;
    uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0;
    
    ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams(
        tokenIn,
        tokenOut,
        fee,
        recipient,
        deadline,
        amountIn,
        amountOutMinimum,
        sqrtPriceLimitX96
    );
    
    uniswapRouter.exactInputSingle{ value: msg.value }(params);
    uniswapRouter.refundETH();
    
    // refund leftover ETH to user
    (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }("");
    require(success, "refund failed");
  }
  
  function convertEthToExactDai(uint256 daiAmount) external payable {
    require(daiAmount > 0, "Must pass non 0 DAI amount");
    require(msg.value > 0, "Must pass non 0 ETH amount");
      
    uint256 deadline = block.timestamp + 15; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!
    address tokenIn = WETH9;
    address tokenOut = DAI;
    uint24 fee = 3000;
    address recipient = msg.sender;
    uint256 amountOut = daiAmount;
    uint256 amountInMaximum = msg.value;
    uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0;

    ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter.ExactOutputSingleParams(
        tokenIn,
        tokenOut,
        fee,
        recipient,
        deadline,
        amountOut,
        amountInMaximum,
        sqrtPriceLimitX96
    );

    uniswapRouter.exactOutputSingle{ value: msg.value }(params);
    uniswapRouter.refundETH();

    // refund leftover ETH to user
    (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }("");
    require(success, "refund failed");
  }
  
  // do not used on-chain, gas inefficient!
  function getEstimatedETHforDAI(uint daiAmount) external payable returns (uint256) {
    address tokenIn = WETH9;
    address tokenOut = DAI;
    uint24 fee = 10000;
    uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0;

    return quoter.quoteExactOutputSingle(
        tokenIn,
        tokenOut,
        fee,
        daiAmount,
        sqrtPriceLimitX96
    );
  }
  
  // important to receive ETH
  receive() payable external {}
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue as well... in my case read-only methods work but the `payable` methods keeps failing with no reason.

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem? I have same problem but when I use remix and deploy it to the Ropsten testnet it works!

Comment: Same issue here, anyone found what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old answer, but I Was curious and I went through your contract. What I noticed, is that you are forking mainnet, but the WETH9 address you are using appears to be the WETH address inside Kovan

For simplicity you can find the address of Kovan and Mainnet at the end of this Gnosis repo - https://github.com/gnosis/canonical-weth

The correct WETH address on mainnet is [0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2](https://etherscan.io/address/0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2)